# How to leave socket connection open after application closes?

Tags: android, ios, sockets, flutter, dart

I have an application where a socket issues an alert when security parameters are exceeded, but when closing the application that connection is terminated and the socket stops issuing the alert. It is of paramount importance to leave this connection open so that the socket will continue to issue alerts even when the application is closed, so that the client has control over these parameters. I would like to know if there is any plugin or some way to leave this connection open even with closed application, either leaving a thread running or something.

```
 initSocket() async {
 socket =
  await manager.createInstance(SocketOptions("http://0.0.0.0:9999"));
  socket.onConnect((data) {
  print("connected...");
  print(data);
  socket.emit("message", ["mensagem nova2"]);
  });
 socket.connect();
}
```

Comment: Add some  code..

Comment: In the passed for iOS, you were able to enable background audio and play an audio clip to keep the app running in the background.  Trick is to use a silent audio clip.  It's been a few years since I used that trick, but it's worth a shot to see if it still works.  Welcome to SO too.

Comment: Try use a Forground Service to keep your connection open

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: @TonyLin would you have any examples of this flutter implementation?